# How to assign SFMC campaigns with Tags programmatically?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I have a list of tags that every campaign have to be assigned to. I'm trying to use the api to accomplish this task.

I found the endpoint below to associate tags with objects, however, as I was unable to get the Objectids for campaigns, I haven't been able to successfully associate the tags with campaigns.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createTags.htm

Has anyone done it before? Is there a way to get the object ids for campaigns as the ones I tried to use don't return objectids (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getCampaign.htm?search_text=campaign).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working using campaignID as the value for objectids on the payload. The issue was the Read/Write permission on the API for tags was missing.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createTags.htm